# how can store attributes in cocoa touch

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, attributes, property-list

i am coding a program for iPhone using Xcode. i defined some attributes for user interface components like uibutton, uilabel etc in property list file. i defined one attribute as real named "cornerradius". Now, how can i get this value from plist correctly to assign CGFloat? Is property list the best way to define attributes? what are my options, any tutorials you recommend?

in plist:
    key cornerradius /key
    real 6.0 /real

in code:

```
NSDecimal cornerRadius;
cornerRadius = [[[dao libraryItemAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"cornerradius"] decimalValue];
[layer setCornerRadius:(CGFloat)cornerRadius];
```

Comment: Not an Xcode question. Xcode is just the IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for program wide scope you should use [NSUserDefaultsController](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSUserDefaultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)
, keep in mind that with a plist you will be only be able to store and retrieve values, like NSNumber, NSString, NSArray, NSDictionary...

```
NSUserDefaults * standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[standardUserDefaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:7] forKey:@"someKey"];
[standardUserDefaults synchronize];//save to disk
// now use it
NSNumber * someNumber = [standardUserDefaults objectForKey:@"someKey"];
int someInt = [someNumber intValue];
```